# Drawing a line over an svg image

Tags: html, css, image, svg, draw

how would I draw the line to go over instead of under the svg image?

```
<html>
<head>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="1000" style="stroke:#006600; stroke-width:20"/>
</svg>
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Weakness_of_Turing_test_1.svg"  type="image/svg+xml" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" />
</html>
```

You can run the code here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_div_test

Edit: Code that works (at least on firefox, for safari the file extension has to be .xhtml)-

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="7in" height="4in" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <image width="600px" height="400px" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Weakness_of_Turing_test_1.svg"> </image>
     <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="500" y2="1000" style="stroke:#006600; stroke-width:15"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then probably you want to include the image inside `<svg>`:

```
<html>
<head>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Weakness_of_Turing_test_1.svg"  width="1000" height="1000" />
    <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="1000" style="stroke:#006600; stroke-width:20"/>
</svg>
</html>
```

Comment: Got it to work by modifying your version! (I updated the question with the code)... It works fine on firefox but fails on safari (just a bordered empty white box appearing).. Any idea why? Thanks!!

Comment: Kind sir: apparently on Safari, xml-html related files have to be explicitly renamed to a .xhtml extension to work.. The final working piece of code is updated in my question.. Much obliged!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to place `<svg>` after the image like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Weakness_of_Turing_test_1.svg"  type="image/svg+xml" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" />
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="1000" style="stroke:#006600; stroke-width:20"/>
</svg>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, the image still covers the line.. ;(

Answer (score 0):

for you to have the line on top of the image, it has to be after it in the dom.
SVG renders shapes and images in the order that it finds in the dom.
Note that there is no z-index attribute in the SVG specifications, so you just can't use that.
All you can do is place the line after the image in the dom.

Another note: you can manipulate SVG through Javascript, so you can manipulate the dom using normal javascript functions